# Is the rank of a relatively free group... ill-defined in general?

Tags: group-theory, universal-algebra

A *relatively free* algebra $F$ has a free generating set (basis) $X$ such that any map $f : X \to F$ can be extended to an endomorphism of $F$. It is known that, in general the notion of rank of $F$ (as the cardinality of a basis of $F$) is not well-defined, that is, there are examples of relatively free algebras whose bases are not necessarily of the same cardinality.

**Question:**

What about relatively free groups? It seems likely that the rank of a relatively free group $F$ must not be well-defined in general. Surely, in some nice cases when, for instance, the abelianization $F/[F,F]$ of $F$ is a free abelian group, the rank of $F$ *is* well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of relatively free group in a variety of groups is well defined.

See pages 11 to 12 of Hanna Neumann's Varieties of Groups.  $F/[F,F]$ is either a free abelian group or a free abelian group of exponent *m*, and in either case it is a free module over a PID and has a well-defined rank, which is in fact the rank of the free generating set *X*.

Comment: What if F=[F,F]? It seems to be possible. In this case no information can be derived from the abelianization.

Comment: The only laws outside of the commutator subgroup are (equivalent mod the commutator subgroup to) exponent laws, so if F=[F,F], then the exponent of F is 1, and so indeed every relatively free group in that variety is the group of order 1, and so the rank is not well-defined.  However, most people ignore the variety of groups of order 1.

Comment: Ah, clear. Thanks!